# Can't receive text message using SNS python Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I've read everything possible about SNS and I can't figure out why any text messages are sent from an aws lambda function.

My function can't be more simple:

```
def send_sms(message):
    print ("sending message...")
    print(message)
    client = boto3.client("sns")
    response = client.publish(
        PhoneNumber="+336xxxxxxxxx",
        Message=message
    )
    print (response)
```

I'm using an SNSFullAccess for this lambda function.

And my log for the print (response) are:

> {'MessageId': '6e9aa592-4ff7-5cf1-be92-ffe34ca16120',
> 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId':
> '5d73d693-b584-5ecb-926f-8ce2b6d2831a', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
> 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid':
> '5d73d693-b584-5ecb-926f-8ce2b6d2831a', 'content-type': 'text/xml',
> 'content-length': '294', 'date': 'Sun, 30 Jan 2022 21:20:22 GMT'},
> 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

Comment: Do you have XRay Tracing configured? Do you see anything in CloudWatch for SNS?

Comment: See [How do I troubleshoot mobile text message (SMS) failures in Amazon SNS?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-troubleshoot-sms-message-failures/).

Comment: @JohnGlenn thanks for your answer, there is nothing wrong on Cloudwatch as you can see it on my post

Comment: @jarmod I already had a loot on this page and nothing from here can help me

Comment: Have you activated [Amazon SNS topic delivery logs for SMS messages](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/)? It gives a detailed log for each message, as opposed to the above response to the API call. Does it work if you run the code on your own computer (instead of in an AWS Lambda function)? That will help separate a potential SNS problem from Lambda.

Comment: @rastafalow Your post shows that you handed off a message to SNS, but thay doesn't mean that everything is fine. If SNS encounters an error actually delivering the message, that could show up in CloudWatch logs.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein that was that, I had to add my phone number to SNS

Comment: What do you mean by "had to add my phone number to SNS"? Did you create an SNS Topic and then subscribe to it? Your code should work without requiring an SNS Topic, and is commonly used when sending messages to individual phone numbers.